# How can I combine two Entity Framework calls into one?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

So I have the following code:

```
    var MAX_VOLUME = (from b in context.TRANSPORT_PLANNER_TRACK_CAP.Where(b => b.WAREHOUSE.Equals(warehouse)) select b.MAX_VOLUME).SingleOrDefault();
    var MAX_WEIGHT = (from b in context.TRANSPORT_PLANNER_TRACK_CAP.Where(b => b.WAREHOUSE.Equals(warehouse)) select b.MAX_WEIGHT).SingleOrDefault();
string maxVolume = MAX_VOLUME.ToString();
string maxWeight = MAX_WEIGHT.ToString();
```

I want to combine these two statements into a single EF call, to reduce redundancy. What's the best approach?

Answer (score 5):

```
var result = (from b in context.TRANSPORT_PLANNER_TRACK_CAP
              where b.WAREHOUSE.Equals(warehouse)
              select new { b.MAX_VOLUME, b.MAX_WEIGHT}).SingleOrDefault();
```

Then just reference it as:

```
result.MAX_WEIGHT or result.MAX_VOLUME
```